# How to construct a binary tree using a level order traversal sequence

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

How to construct a binary tree using a level order traversal sequence, for example from sequence {1,2,3,#,#,4,#,#,5}, we can construct a binary tree like this:

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
      /
     4
      \
       5
```

where '#' signifies a path terminator where no node exists below.

Finally I implement Pham Trung's algorithm by c++

```
struct TreeNode
{
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    int val;

    TreeNode(int x): left(NULL), right(NULL), val(x) {}
};
TreeNode *build_tree(char nodes[], int n)
{
    TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(nodes[0] - '0'); 
    queue<TreeNode*> q;
    bool is_left = true;
    TreeNode *cur = NULL;
    q.push(root);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        TreeNode *node = NULL;
        if (nodes[i] != '#') {
            node = new TreeNode(nodes[i] - '0');
            q.push(node);
        }

        if (is_left) {
            cur = q.front();
            q.pop();
            cur->left = node;
            is_left = false;
        } else {
            cur->right = node;
            is_left = true;
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume using array `int[]data` with 0-based index, we have a simple function to get children:

- Left child

  ```
    int getLeftChild(int index){
       if(index*2 + 1 >= data.length)
          return -1;// -1 Means out of bound
       return data[(index*2) + 1];
    }
  ```
- Right child

  ```
    int getRightChild(int index){
       if(index*2 + 2 >= data.length)
          return -1;// -1 Means out of bound           
       return data[(index*2) + 2];
    }
  ```

Edit:
Ok, so by maintaining a queue, we can build this binary tree.

We use a queue to maintain those nodes that are not yet processed.

Using a variable count to keep track of the number of children added for the current node.

First, create a root node, assign it as the current node.
So starting from index 1 (index 0 is the root), as the count is 0, we add this node as left child of the current node.
Increase count. If this node is not '#', add it to the queue.

Moving to the next index, the count is 1, so we add this as right child of current node, reset count to 0 and update current node (by assigning the current node as the first element in the queue). If this node is not '#', add it to the queue.

```
     int count = 0;
     Queue q = new Queue();
     q.add(new Node(data[0]);
     Node cur = null;
     for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
        Node node = new Node(data[i]);
        if(count == 0){
           cur = q.dequeue();           
        }
        if(count==0){
          count++;
          cur.leftChild = node;
        }else {
          count = 0;
          cur.rightChild = node;
        }
        if(data[i] != '#'){
          q.enqueue(node);
        }
     }    



    class Node{
       int data;
       Node leftChild, rightChild;
    }
```

**Note**: this should only work for a binary tree and not BST.

Comment: you see ,in the array {1,2,3,#,#,4,#,#,5}, element 4's left child should be # and 5, but 4's index is 5, #'s index is 7, 5's index is 8

Comment: @bigpotato can you describe more about your array? How to know which element is whose child? normally, mine is how an array represent a binary tree.

Comment: please look at the description of my question, there is an example

Comment: @bigpotato so please set it as answer for the question :)

Comment: ,ok, actually '#' represent a dummy node, so I set node to be null when its data is '#' which can construct a tree properly.

Comment: Try for {1,2,3,2,#,4,#,#,5}, this approach will fail coz this approach assumes the first element in next level must be a left/right child of previous level's leftmost parent.

Since in your case, 4 was the only node at level-3 the next level element 5 got assigned to 4 as right child

But if at level-3 there were 2, 4 then 5 would have been assigned as right child of 2. which is incorrect. Hence we can't reconstruct a BST from just level-order input. unless the tree is FULL/PERFECT.

Comment: @mahee96 The array represents the children of non-null nodes in the order they were listed. You are misled by the word `level`.

Comment: @mahee96 You could find this binary tree representation largely used on Leetcode as a way to specify input, for example, https://leetcode.com/problems/recover-binary-search-tree/. Also, this link describes array representation of binary tree: http://www.btechsmartclass.com/data_structures/binary-tree-representations.html

Comment: @PhamTrung I do get that # was a token to represent null children of non null node, but that's not the problem or confusion. The issue is that, this approach assumes current node can have max 2 children(null or non-null) and the input level order is based on this. But it ignores the fact that null children's children are not included in the input, ie {1,2,3,#,#,4,#,#,5} means {{1},{2,3},{#,#,4,#},{#,5}} where the last level elements # and 5 are children of non null parent 4.

Comment: @mahee96 I don't get your point. You could use leetcode graphical tool to see how the input should look like. This is for your example, https://ibb.co/HTvdJLT, which node `2` is the parent of `5` is correct.

Comment: @PhamTrung, okay now that I see there is a key point that I missed maybe, I saw this to be a BST but the question was just about binary tree.

Comment: coz if it were a BST then 2 can't be left child of 1 and if so this would defy BST properties which I was keying on.

Comment: @PhamTrung, can you please update your answer to distinguish about the application of this approach to binary tree and it wouldn't apply to BST unless the input too is a valid level order traversal from a BST. (I can't change my vote unless answer is updated).

Comment: @mahee96 done, oh yes, I also missed that point about BST from your earlier comment, should have saved us some time. Glad that we both learned smt!

Comment: This solution doesn't work. If your input is `[6,x,8,4,x]`, this doesn't return the correct tree.

Comment: @Nathan What is the correct tree? could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

### we can build this binary tree from level order traversal by maintaining a queue. Queue is used to maintain those nodes that are not yet processed.

> 1. Using a variable count(index variable) to keep track of the number of children added for the current node.
> 2. First, create a root node, assign it as the current node. So starting from index 1,
>      index value is 1 means, we will add the next value as left node.
>      index value is 2 means we will add the next value as right node and index value 2 means that we have added left and right node, then do the same for the remaining nodes.
> 3. if arr value is -1
>
> 3.a. if index value is 1,i.e., there is no left node then change the index variable to add right node.
>   3.b. if index value is 2, i.e, there is no right node then we have repeat this step for the remaining.

```
static class Node{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node(int d){
        data=d;
        left=null;
        right=null;
    }
}
```

public static Node constBT(int arr[],int n){

```
    Node root=null;
    Node curr=null;
    int index=0;
    Queue<Node> q=new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        if(root==null){
            root=new Node(arr[i]);
            q.add(root);
            curr=q.peek();
            index=1;
        }else{
            if(arr[i]==-1){

                 if(index==1)
                    index=2;
                else{
                    q.remove();
                    curr=q.peek();
                    index=1;

                }
            }

            else if(index==1){
                curr.left=new Node(arr[i]);
                q.add(curr.left);
                index=2;

            }else if(index==2){
                curr.right=new Node(arr[i]);
                q.add(curr.right);
                q.remove();
                curr=q.peek();
                index=1;
            }

        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My approach is similar to Pham Trung yet intutive. We would maintain an array of Nodes of given data instead of using a queue. We would do reverse engineering on BFS using queue. because BFS for a tree is basically its Level Order Traversal (LOT).

It is important to note that we should have the NULL childs of an node for the LOT to be unique and the reconstruction of Tree from LOT to be possible.

In this case LOT : `1,2,3,-1,-1,4,-1,-1,5`
where I have used -1 instead of '#' to represent NULLs 
And Tree is

```
           1
        /    \
       2      3
      / \    /
    -1  -1  4
           / \
         -1   5
```

Here, we can easily see that when 1 is popped from the BFS queue, it pushed its left child
(2) and right child (3) in the queue. Similary, for 2 it pushed -1 (NULL) for both of its children. And the process is continued. 
So, we can  follow the following pseudo code to generate the tree rooted at LOT[0]

```
j = 1
For every node in LOT:
  if n<=j: break
  if node  != NULL:
    make LOT[j] left child of node 
    if n<=j+1: break
    make LOT[j+1]  right child of node
  j <- j+2
```

Finally, C++ code for the same 
**Class Declaration and Preorder traversal**

```
class Node{
public:
    int val;
    Node* lft, *rgt;
    Node(int x ):val(x) {lft=rgt=nullptr;}
};


void preorder(Node* root) {
    if(!root)   return;
    cout<<root->val<<" ";
    preorder(root->lft);
    preorder(root->rgt);
}
```

**Restoring Tree from LOT Logic**

```
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,-1,-1,4,-1,-1,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    Node* brr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
        if(arr[i]==-1)  brr[i] = nullptr;
        else brr[i] = new Node(arr[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0,j=1;j<n;i++) {
        if(!brr[i]) continue;
        brr[i]->lft = brr[j++];
        if(j<n) brr[i]->rgt = brr[j++];
    }
    preorder(brr[0]);
}
```

**Output**: `1 2 3 4 5`