# How to construct a binary tree from level order array?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-heap

I'm working on a coding question and right now I'm bit confused. If I'm given an array which represents level order traversal of a binary tree. How do I construct a tree from that?

So far here is my thought process so far: I know the `0th` index is the `root`, `leftChild = 2*i+1` and `rightChild = 2*i+2`.

Here is what I have so far and I don't think its right:

```
public Tree buildTree(ArrayList<Tree> arr, int i) {
    if (i > list.size() - 1) {
        return null;
    }

    root = list.get(i);
    root.LeftChild = buildTree(arr, 2*i+1);
    root.RightChild = buildTree(arr, 2*i+2);

    return root;
}
```

my `i` starts at 0, Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide link to the question ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code would only work with [complete binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), a special case of binary trees.

You ***can't*** construct generic binary tree just from the level order traversal.

You need ***two*** traversal of which ***one must be an inorder traversal***.

Following combination can uniquely identify a tree.

- Inorder and Preorder.
- Inorder and Postorder.
- Inorder and Level-order.

Though there is a possibility to construct tree (given only level order traversal) if you've some separators in the given array like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754060/how-to-construct-a-binary-tree-using-a-level-order-traversal-sequence).

Comment: It is a complete binary tree

Comment: @RockySingh your code seems to work fine for complete binary tree. Did you tried the edge cases like tree with 0,1, half complete, fully complete nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine...although it's strange that your method takes in an `ArrayList<Tree>` instead of an `ArrayList<Node>`. Why don't you think it's right? How are you testing your method? What kind of errors are you getting?